# Rename Node Sockets

Tags: node-editor

Is there a way to rename the sockets on a group node? This would be useful. Googling produces some unsettling results as it seems it is a feature being developed by a third party and maybe as an addon?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by clicking the node and open up the **properties panel** by hitting <kbd>N</kbd> within the node editor. With this you can edit **name, label, outputs and inputs** of the node.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes! I just found it myself! I was about to delete the question!

Comment: No problem, here is the link if you're interested in looking: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be @poor

Comment: I won't delete it